# Adding a br tag on Enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add a `<br />` tag each time enter is pressed inside a `keyup` function? I have no clue as to how this should be done.

```
.on("keyup", ".club", function() {
     //detect enter key to add br tags
});
```

Comment: _//detect enter key to add br tags_ - it's the right way. What have you tried so far?

Comment: can you elaborate more what exactly do you want to achieve?  what is the element type for which you are capturing keyup event? Is it the same element that you want to add a <br /> tag?

Comment: @SameerAzazi thanks I'm adding text to a DIV. I just want to detect whenever there is a newline (ENTER KEY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.on("keyup", ".club", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        var $this = $(this); // Caching
        $this.val($this.val() + '<br />');

        // OR

        $this.val($this.val() + '\n\r');
    }
});
```

Comment: what's the difference between `'<br />' and `'\n\r'` ? is that html and php

Comment: If `.club` is textarea you should use `\n\r`

Comment: `this.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));` is much much much faster. This forgoes the parsing of the current element to string, appending a new string to it resulting in another new string, then parsing that string back to html and rendering it. When not needed, try to avoid string html for speed, especially if people need to type. If you do this in a 10.000 letter document with html markup, this will be slow as hell. Whilst my suggestion will compile super fast, which is what you want in an UI enviroment. Also, try to instantiate as least as possible jQuery instances as possible.

Comment: so instead of $(this).val($(this).val()+"xxxx"); do var elem = $(this);elem.val(elem.val()+"xxx"); this saves a lot of time in instantiating the object, and it's easier on the garbage collector to clean up.